# Programmatically change wifi password on DLink wireless router

Tags: api, automation, passwords, wifi

I'm attempting to script changing the wifi password on a DLink wireless router.

(I need to set the password to a new random value every day at a particular time, for reasons that have nothing to do with the question.)

I've started using Perl and WWW::Mechanize, which has been a reliable technique for tasks of this type in the past, but the forms all use javascripty methods rather than straight HTML forms.

Before I waste my morning watching traffic on Firebug and figuring out what's going on, I wondered if this is an already-solved problem. Does anyone know of either a direct API for doing this, or have an automation method for doing this?

(Yes, I could probably use Selenium or the like, but I'm really hoping to run something on my Raspberry Pi, rather than having it have to run on a machine with a browser.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use PhantomJS on Raspberry Pi. PhantomJS is a headless, lightweight WebKit browser which can be used for web automation. It can support Javascript.

You can download the [PhantomJS for Raspberry Pi here](https://github.com/aeberhardo/phantomjs-linux-armv6l).

Alternatively, you can also check this software: [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/).